# How can I migrate a single page application to a site with many URLs for SEO?

Tags: seo, redirects, url, migration, single-page-application

I will be migrating a single page application (SPA) to a normal URL structured site.

Usually I would map the old URLs to the new URLs and use 301 redirects to the relevant URLs.  In this case, that is difficult since the one page site is ranking for multiple terms.

Do you have any idea how to get around this? I though internal linking is the only way to gain at least a bit of the page rank for the relevant terms but I'm still working on it.

Comment: Does the SPA use hash URLs or push state?  Or does the URL never change the entire time the SPA is used?

Comment: The site is running on wordpress and it doesnt use hashtags the URL never changes except Contact page and one more page i cant recall right now. The only i can think of is make the new site pages relevant to the keywords the homepage is ranking for Google may not pass 100% of page rank but it would be able to see a relationship or atleast i hope so.

Comment: I didn't know WordPress could be made into an SPA.

Comment: I dont have allot information about the technical background of the website i know for sure is a wordpress and i know is custom made. I could have a chat with the developers but i dont think it would be much of use at this moment since the migration is starting soon.

Comment: Is it possible that this is just a website where most of the content is on a single page? SPA (single-page application) has a very specific technical meaning.